# Jenkins issue while parsing POMS

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jboss

Why is Jenkins throwing this errors at the end though the maven compilation succeeded?

Inside dependency management of Parent POM

```
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
            <version>${org.jboss.spec.jboss.javaee.spec.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

In child pom

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.jms</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-jms-api_2.0_spec</artifactId>        
   </dependency>
```

The jars mentioned here are added as part of `javaee7.0 pom`. I have added the scope as import in the parent pom.

```
ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.spec.javax.jms:jboss-jms-api_2.0_spec:jar is missing. @ line 105, column 21

[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.spec.javax.jms:jboss-jms-api_2.0_spec:jar is missing. @ line 102, column 20

[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar is missing. @ line 110, column 20

[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: com.xyz.test:persistence-datamodel:jar -> duplicate declaration of version (?) @ line 126, column 21

[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.spec.javax.jms:jboss-jms-api_2.0_spec:jar is missing. @ line 30, column 20

[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar is missing. @ line 34, column 19

[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar is missing. @ line 59, column 20

[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs-all:pom is missing. @ line 153, column 24

[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet:jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec:jar is missing. @ line 159, column 23

[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: com.xyz.test:xab-commands:ejb -> version (?) vs 3.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT @ line 270, column 21
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar -> duplicate declaration of version (?) @ line 200, column 21
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar -> duplicate declaration of version (?) @ line 206, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.spec.javax.jms:jboss-jms-api_2.0_spec:jar is missing. @ line 68, column 18
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.spec.javax.jms:jboss-jms-api_2.0_spec:jar is missing. @ line 69, column 21

    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:364)
    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.buildProjects(MavenEmbedder.java:361)
    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.readProjects(MavenEmbedder.java:331)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.invoke(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1290)
```

Comment: Can you post a copy of your POM file, perhaps?

Comment: I have edited the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Here `you have missed some jars` to add the version in dependency and `some jars are duplicate`. For this reason, this error is occurred.

**So don't forget to add the version in dependency.**

### Missing Jars:

1. jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec:jar
2. jboss-jms-api_2.0_spec:jar
3. javax.mail:jar

### Use below dependency for adding the missing jars.

> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
>   <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
>   <version>1.4.7</version> <!-- You have missed to add this version-->
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
>   <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
>   <version>3.1.0</version> <!-- You have missed to add this version-->
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.jms</groupId>
>   <artifactId>jboss-jms-api_2.0_spec</artifactId>
>   <version>1.0.0.Final</version> <!-- You have missed to add this version-->
> </dependency>
> ```

---

Some jars are duplicate. Which causes the below error. So `remove duplicate dependency`

```
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: com.xyz.test:xab-commands:ejb -> version (?) vs 3.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT @ line 270, column 21
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar -> duplicate declaration of version (?) @ line 200, column 21
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar -> duplicate declaration of version (?) @ line 206, column 21
```

---

### UPDATE:

I have given a sample. Hope it will clarify you.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

If there groupId is same in parent and child. Then it is not needed to add version in child pom.

Comment: The jars are part of the parent pom. I have used the import scope to add all these jars. My question is maven always succeeds. It's just Jenkins failing. Does Jenkins do some extra parsing?

Comment: @Guru You have missed to add the version. Please check dependency i have added.

Comment: But the version comes because of import in the parent pom.. Why do I need to explicitly add in the child?

Comment: @Guru You have miss understand on that. if you want to use it from your parent, then it need to specify. <version>${org.jboss.spec.jboss.javaee.spec.version}</version> this is actually for jboss-javaee-7.0. So best practice is using as I suggested. In some cases you can specify in your parent pom.xml

Comment: I have added the Pom in import. If I see the effective POM, all these jars are mentioned with version.